# Rename files with sequence to new sequence

Tags: linux, bash, file, sequence, rename

I have files in a directory which I need to rename with a bash script.
Bellow you see the old name of the file and what the new filename must be.

OLDNAME -> NEWNAME
FILE71   -> 001
FILE72   -> 002
FILE73   -> 003
FILE74   -> 004
FILE75   -> 005
FILE76   -> 006
FILE77   -> 007
FILE78   -> 008
FILE79   -> 009
FILE80   -> 010

The OLDNAME and NEWNAME should be exact as in the example, so:
old file name FILE73 must became new file name 003, FILE74 must be 004 and FILE80 must be 010

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what exactly you want? have you want to rename all file name to `001....so on`?

Comment: changed the question, I hope it is more clear now.

Comment: This isn't a place to ask people to write your code. What have you tried, and what are the specific problems you are facing?

Comment: Your edit really doesn't help explain the problem at all. Based on what principle are the names getting changed? If it's just changing the exact OLDNAMES -> NEWNAMES then why haven't you accepted [Mark Setchell's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22710785/3076724)? If it's changing files in a sorted order like `FILE{71,72,73,74...SOMELARGENUMBER}` to `{001,002,003,004...SOMELARGENUMBER}` then you should write that in question and how big `SOMELARGENUMBER` is.

Answer (score 9):

Here you go:

```
#!/bin/bash
mv FILE71 001
mv FILE72 002
mv FILE73 003
mv FILE74 004
mv FILE75 005
mv FILE76 006
mv FILE77 007
mv FILE78 008
mv FILE79 009
mv FILE80 010
```

Comment: I can't believe you did all that for free.  Amazing.  The power of open source!

Comment: @JohnZwinck I got a big smile as my reward which was plenty! Laughter is the best medicine :-)

Comment: This made my day, have an upvote! :-)

Comment: +1: This was James Blunt's inspiration behind the song "You're beautiful"!!

Answer (score 0):

Run simple `for..loop` and done

```
#!/bin/bash
files=$(find mypath -maxdepth 1 -type f | sort -u)
a=1
for i in $files; do
  new=$(printf "%03d" ${a}) 
  mv ${i} mypath/${new}
  let a=a+1
done
```

Comment: Almost working :-), but also the filename FILE73 must be 003 and FILE77 must be 007 etc. With you outcome its random.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another variant of @MarkSetchell 's script

```
#!/bin/bash
while read orig new
do
    echo mv "$orig" "$new"
done <<EOF
FILE71 001
FILE72 002
FILE73 003
FILE74 004
FILE75 005
FILE76 006
FILE77 007
FILE78 008
FILE79 009
FILE80 010
EOF
```

or you can try

```
join -o"1.2 2.2" \
    <(find . -maxdepth 1 -name FILE\* -print|cat -n) \
    <(seq -f "%03g" 1000|cat -n) |\
    xargs -n2 echo
```

you need replace the `echo` with another command - it is up to you... ;)

Comment: Thanks for the example. Problem with the outcome is that the result is this:

./FILE73 001
./FILE71 002
./FILE80 003
./FILE72 004

While I need:
./FILE73 003
./FILE71 001
./FILE80 010
./FILE72 002